# Compare SQL Timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I use ADO.NET to retrieve a table from sql2k server, where one of the field is timestamp type.
I want to compare this field for concurrency checking, but I found that the value returned by ADO.NET is an array of byte. Can I just convert it to say long, or do I need to compare it byte by byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(var)` to compare / display.
I believe `var.Equals(var2)` will also work or `Object.Equals(var1, var2)`

If you'd doing an update, it's better to let the CRUD proc do this and return 0 for results affected when you run the proc and handle it there.  Opposed to querying for the current timestamp.